# Format errors: 2 column math problem set; vertical enumeration with TIKz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, multicolumn

I'm trying to create a 2 column, vertically enumerated problem set for my math students trying to learn the distributive property.

Using some wonderful Tikz code by @Peter Grill & @Tarass, I have beautiful arrows showing the distribution.

Several problems I'm trying to solve:

1. vertically enumerating each problem (which is followed step by step solution.
2. "turning off" solutions so I can hand out just the problems to students
3. drawing a box around the final solution

For my mwe I have only included 1 problem, but will need 4 - 5 problems per column.

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

```
    \documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=70,in=130,distance=0.5cm,#1] (MarkA.north) to (MarkC.north);
    \draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=50,in=140,distance=0.3cm,#2] (MarkA.north) to (MarkB.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
    \newlength{\MyL}

\newcommand{\TkM}[2]{%
    \settowidth{\MyL}{#2}
    #2\hspace{-\MyL}\makebox[\MyL]{\tikzmark{#1}}
    }

\begin{document}
Use distributive property to simplify the expressions below.
 \begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\begin{align*}
%[\TkM{MarkA}{a}(\TkM{MarkB}{b}+\TkM{MarkC}{c})=ab+ac%
%\DrawBox{OrangeRed,distance=0.45cm,in=130,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt}{Cerulean,out=65,in=110,distance=0.3cm,shorten >=3.5pt,shorten <=3pt}\]%
\item
-(2x+5)&=(\TkM{MarkA}{-1})(\TkM{MarkB}{2x}+\TkM{MarkC}{5})
\DrawBox{OrangeRed,distance=0.6cm}{Cerulean,out=60,in=110,distance=0.4cm}\\
       &=(-1)(2x)+(-1)(5)\\
       &=-2x+(-5)\\
       &=-2x-5
       \item
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** Numbering: instead of `itemize` it is better to use the question number itself.

**(2)** The command `\noprintanswers`  will suppress explicit solutions, but will leave room for student responses. This space can be a blank box, lines or dotted lines, as shown in the example. Its size can be chosen using the optional parameter.

**(3)** The requested solution for a question is framed.

**(4)** `\multicolumn` tries to balance columns, so unwanted white space can appear between elements. To avoid this situation   `\raggedcolumns` is being used.

**(5)** It may happen that the question is placed at the bottom left column and the solution at the top of the right column. To keep both together, a minipage can be used (question #3 in the example).

**Instructor page**

[image: c]

**Student page**

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

 \noprintanswers % without answers <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
   
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt} % inter column rule width 
\setlength{\columnsep}{15.0pt}  % column separation

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}
\newcommand{\tikzmarkx}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}
\newcommand{\DrawBox}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=70,in=130,distance=0.5cm,#1] (MarkA.north) to (MarkC.north);
    \draw[->,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt,out=50,in=140,distance=0.3cm,#2] (MarkA.north) to (MarkB.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newlength{\MyL}

\newcommand{\TkM}[2]{%
\settowidth{\MyL}{#2}
#2\hspace{-\MyL}\makebox[\MyL]{\tikzmarkx{#1}}
}


\begin{document}
    
\section*{ Use distributive property to simplify the expressions below}
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \raggedcolumns % do not balance the columns to avoid extra vertical space<<<<<<

    \begin{questions}
    
        \question Did you mutter something? % Q 1
        \begin{solutionorlines}[3in]
        The paralogisms of practical
        reason are what first give rise to the architectonic of practical
        reason. As will easily be shown in the next section, reason would
        thereby be made to contradict, in view of these considerations, the
        Ideal of practical reason, yet the manifold depends on the phenomena.
        Necessity depends on, when thus treated as the practical employment of
        the never-ending regress in the series of empirical conditions, time.
        \end{solutionorlines}
    
        %\printanswers % show this answer <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \question -(2x+5)        % Q 2
        \begin{solutionorlines}[2in]
            \begin{align*}          
            -(2x+5) &=(\TkM{MarkA}{-1})(\TkM{MarkB}{2x}+\TkM{MarkC}{5})
            \DrawBox{OrangeRed,distance=0.6cm}{Cerulean,out=60,in=110,distance=0.4cm}\\
            &=(-1)(2x)+(-1)(5)\\
            &=-2x+(-5)\\
            &=\fbox{-2x-5}
        \end{align*}
        \end{solutionorlines}       
        \noprintanswers
    
        %The minipage will keep the question and the solution together <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\columnwidth-\leftmargin} % Q 3    
            
        \question (3x+5)
        
        \begin{solutionorbox}[2in]
            \begin{align*}      
                (3x+5) &=(\TkM{MarkA}{1})(\TkM{MarkB}{3x}+\TkM{MarkC}{5})
                \DrawBox{OrangeRed,distance=0.6cm}{Cerulean,out=60,in=110,distance=0.4cm}\\
                &=(3x)+(5)\\
                &=\fbox{3x-5}
            \end{align*}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        \end{minipage}
        
        \question (4x+5)  % Q 4     
        \begin{solutionorbox}[3in]
            \begin{align*}
                (4x+5) &=(\TkM{MarkA}{1})(\TkM{MarkB}{4x}+\TkM{MarkC}{5})
                \DrawBox{OrangeRed,distance=0.6cm}{Cerulean,out=60,in=110,distance=0.4cm}\\
                &=(4x)+(5)\\
                &=\fbox{4x-5}
            \end{align*}
        \end{solutionorbox}
        
        \question -(5x+5)  % Q 5            
        \begin{solutionordottedlines}[1.5in]
            \begin{align*}          
                -(2x+5) &=(\TkM{MarkA}{-1})(\TkM{MarkB}{5x}+\TkM{MarkC}{5})
                \DrawBox{OrangeRed,distance=0.6cm}{Cerulean,out=60,in=110,distance=0.4cm}\\
                &=(-1)(5x)+(-1)(5)\\
                &=-5x+(-5)\\
                &=\fbox{-5x-5}
            \end{align*}
        \end{solutionordottedlines}
    \end{questions}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

**(6)** `\printanswers` and `\noprintanswers` can be used to show a single example solution to guide students. For example

```
    \printanswers % show this answer <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \question -(2x+5)        % Q 2
    \begin{solutionorlines}[2in]
        \begin{align*}          
        -(2x+5) &=(\TkM{MarkA}{-1})(\TkM{MarkB}{2x}+\TkM{MarkC}{5})
        \DrawBox{OrangeRed,distance=0.6cm}{Cerulean,out=60,in=110,distance=0.4cm}\\
        &=(-1)(2x)+(-1)(5)\\
        &=-2x+(-5)\\
        &=\fbox{-2x-5}
    \end{align*}
    \end{solutionorlines}       
    \noprintanswers
```

will produce

[image: e]

Comment: Thanks for an incredibly helpful and educational response. Will use this immediately with my students! Never would have figured this out on my own.

Comment: @ Simon Dispa ....your suggestion (6) above is spot on....(6) \printanswers and \noprintanswers can be used to show a single example solution to guide students. I wish there was a website for high school maths teachers where we could all share our work. Even asked overleaf.com to host this, but no interest.

Comment: @Siuslaw Math Thank you for your feedback!